# How many times was Dwaraka invaded in the absence of Krishna as narrated in the Mahabharata or other puranas?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana

How many times was Dwaraka invaded in the absence of Krishna as narrated in the Mahabharata or other puranas? One is known to me when king Shalva attacked Dwaraka to avenge the killing of his friend Shishupala by Krishna. Are there any other similar events narrated either in the Mahabharata or in any of the puranas?